# Running `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` in Python 3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, keras, config

I am training to run the line `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` but I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'
```

My version of Python is `3.9.2`, and I am using Tensorflow `1.8.0`, and Keras `2.1.5`. How can I get past this error?

Comment: Is the answer not solved your error?

Comment: yes it does, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) is introduced in `tf` version 2. You're using `tf` < 2 version. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly). FYI, `tf 1.x` use **Graph** execution whereas `tf 2.x` introcuded **Eager** along with **Graph** mode. The Eager execution mode is set as default in `tf 2.x`.

In `tf 1.15.1`

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'
```

To enable eager mode in `tf 1.x`, you need to do it as follows

```
# Tested on tf 1.15.1
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
tf.executing_eagerly() # True
```

In `tf.2.4.1`, it comes by **default**. Please note, though in `tf 2.x` eager mode is set as default, there still are some functionalities that are run in **Graph** mode. So, you can either disable eager mode completely or set it for all. To disable eager mode or enable it for all cases in `tf 2.x`, you would need to set

```
# Disables eager execution.
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

# Disables eager execution of tf.functions.
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)

or 

# Enable eager execution of tf.functions.
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```