# Make TensorFlow use the GPU on an ARM Mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, deep-learning, arm

I have installed `TensorFlow` on an M1 (**ARM**) Mac according to [these instructions](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/153). Everything works fine.

However, model training is happening on the `CPU`. How do I switch training to the `GPU`?

```
In: tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices()
Out: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

In the documentation of [Apple's TensorFlow distribution](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) I found the following slightly confusing [paragraph](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos#additional-information):

> It is not necessary to make any changes to your existing TensorFlow scripts to use ML Compute as a backend for TensorFlow and TensorFlow Addons. There is an optional `mlcompute.set_mlc_device(device_name='any')` API for ML Compute device selection. The default value for device_name is 'any', which means ML Compute will select the best available device on your system, including multiple GPUs on multi-GPU configurations. Other available options are `CPU` and `GPU`. Please note that in eager mode, ML Compute will use the CPU. For example, to choose the CPU device, you may do the following:

```
# Import mlcompute module to use the optional set_mlc_device API for device selection with ML Compute.
from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute

# Select CPU device.
mlcompute.set_mlc_device(device_name='cpu') # Available options are 'cpu', 'gpu', and 'any'.
```

So I try to run:

```
from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute
mlcompute.set_mlc_device(device_name='gpu')
```

and get:

```
WARNING:tensorflow: Eager mode uses the CPU. Switching to the CPU.
```

At this point I am stuck. How can I train `keras` models on the GPU to my MacBook Air?

TensorFlow version: `2.4.0-rc0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

The [tensorflow_macos tf 2.4](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) repository has been archived by the owner. For `tf 2.5`, refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).

---

It's probably not useful to disable the eager execution fully but to `tf. functions`. Try this and check your GPU usages, the warning message can be [misleading](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/71#issuecomment-748444580).

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)
```

---

The current release of [Mac-optimized TensorFlow](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/tag/v0.1alpha3) has several issues that yet not fixed (`TensorFlow 2.4rc0`). Eventually, the eager mode is the default behavior in `TensorFlow 2.x`, and that is also unchanged in the [TensorFlow-MacOS](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/tag/v0.1alpha3). But unlike the official, this optimized version uses **CPU** forcibly for eager mode. As they stated [here](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos#device-selection-optional).

> ... in eager mode, **ML Compute** will use the **CPU**.

That's why even we set explicitly the `device_name='gpu'`, it switches back to CPU as the eager mode is still on.

```
from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute
mlcompute.set_mlc_device(device_name='gpu')

WARNING:tensorflow: Eager mode uses the CPU. Switching to the CPU.
```

[Disabling the eager mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768341/9215780) may work for the program to utilize the GPU, but it's not a general behavior and can lead to such [puzzling performance on both CPU/GPU](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/88). For now, the most appropriate approach can be to choose `device_name='any'`, by that the **ML Compute** will query the available devices on the system and selects the best device(s) for training the network.

Comment: This works as well and puts model training on the GPU. Testing now to see how much existing `tf` code it breaks...

Comment: Also, if possible let's know what's your input data pipelines: `tf. data` or `custom generator`? People also face this issue. You should raise an issue to GitHub there with your findings and set a cross-link here and there for future references. I've found that this issue is mostly with [`tf 2.4`](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/74#).

Comment: I'd like to do that, but can you give some details? E.g. what is the unexpected behavior here? And why do the input data pipelines matter? Ideally I want fully functional TensorFlow no matter the input mode.

Comment: The reason I'm wondering about your input data pipelines is because of the `RuntimeError()` you got for disabling the eager execution and I thought that may be using [`tf. function` decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63220663/9215780) solves the issue or probably makes the code one step forward.

Comment: One unexpected behavior: CPU training seems to be slightly faster than GPU training, even though GPU utilization is >90%.

Comment: And I believe the unexpected behavior is more related to [tensorflow_macos](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) and also [autokeras.ImageClassifier.fit](https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras/blob/0d22c6f6a611cdfc017a24c28c68e7925b7f7feb/autokeras/tasks/image.py#L38). I've encountered this `RuntimeError` on my windows machine with AutoKera while disabling the eager model

Comment: Now the performance issue is more related to the `tensorflow_macros`. Others also faced this issue but dev [yet to solve it](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/88).

Answer (score 1):

Try with turning off the eager execution...
via following

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Let me know if it works.