# Tensorflow on M1 does not use GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu

I set up apple tensorflow as described [here](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos). I tried both the installer script and the conda version, both having the same problem. Below is the cifar10 script to test tensor flow, which reveals that tensorflow does not recognize the GPU. The system monitor also shows that the CPU is used instead of the GPU.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print([x.name for x in device_lib.list_local_devices() if x.device_type == 'GPU'])
from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute
print("is_apple_mlc_enabled %s" % mlcompute.is_apple_mlc_enabled())
print("is_tf_compiled_with_apple_mlc %s" % mlcompute.is_tf_compiled_with_apple_mlc())
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
               'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10,
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

How can I make tensorflow use the GPU instead of the CPU? What am I doing wrong? I also realized that the setup has dependency problem, may they be the cause?

```
(venv) ~ pip check
tensorflow-macos 0.1a3 has requirement gast==0.3.3, but you have gast 0.4.0.
tensorflow-macos 0.1a3 has requirement grpcio~=1.32.0, but you have grpcio 1.33.2.
tensorflow-macos 0.1a3 has requirement numpy~=1.19.2, but you have numpy 1.18.5.
tensorflow-macos 0.1a3 has requirement protobuf~=3.13.0, but you have protobuf 3.15.8.
tensorflow-macos 0.1a3 has requirement tensorflow-estimator~=2.3.0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.4.0.
```

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make TensorFlow use the GPU on an ARM Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167886/make-tensorflow-use-the-gpu-on-an-arm-mac)

Comment: No. I disabled eager execution already. Since the docs state: "Please note that in eager mode, ML Compute will use the CPU"

Comment: Looks like Tensorflow-gpu is not released on Macos. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44751#issuecomment-726210437) comment. Thanks!

Comment: Sure google does not give away time for Apple. But Apple does it [on its own](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos).